Lua socket errors when trying to compile basic ConTeXt documents
Note: I am not entirely sure whether this question is appropriate for the TeX Stack Exchange as this seems to be an issue with my TeX Live installation. But I suppose that the people here would probably have a better understanding of TeX Live distributions than most others, so I'm posting here anyways. Please tell me if this is off-topic.

Firstly, everything here is ran on a Fedora 39 system (technically Asahi Linux). All packages are up to date at the time of posting, and I installed TeX Live via the package texlive-scheme-full.
Here is a basic ConTeXt Mk IV document.
\mainlanguage[en]
\setuppapersize[A4] 
\setupbodyfont[modern,12pt]
\setuphead[chapter][style=\bfc]
\starttext
\startchapter[title=Test]
Hello!
\stopchapter
\stoptext 

I have never ran ConTeXt successfully on this system before, so it attempts to generate format files.
mtx-context     | warning: no format found, forcing remake (commandline driven)
resolvers       | resolving | configuration files already identified
resolvers       | resolving | loading configuration file '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | locating list of '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist' (runtime) (tree:////usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist)
resolvers       | methods | resolving, method 'locators', how 'uri', handler 'tree', argument 'tree:////usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | trees | locator '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist' found
resolvers       | resolving | hash '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist' appended
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | methods | resolving, method 'generators', how 'uri', handler 'file', argument '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | expansions | using cached scan of path '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist', branch '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | methods | resolving, method 'generators', how 'uri', handler 'file', argument '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | expansions | using cached scan of path '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist', branch '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | not saving runtime tree '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | resolving | not saving runtime tree '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist'
resolvers       | resolving | using given filetype 'tex'
resolvers       | methods | resolving, method 'concatinators', how 'tag', tag 'default'
resolvers       | methods | resolving, method 'concatinators', how 'tag', tag 'default'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'cont-en.mkiv' using hash 'tex::cont-en.mkiv'
resolvers       | formats | using tex source file '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-en.mkiv'
resolvers       | formats | using lua stub file '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua'
resolvers       | formats | changing to format path '/home/runxiyu/.cache/texlive/luatex-cache/context/c8ffba5311d077c16376bba44d5fa793/formats/luatex'
resolvers       | formats | executing runner 'make luatex format': /usr/bin/luatex --ini  --lua=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-en.mkiv

But while running /usr/bin/luatex --ini  --lua=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-en.mkiv, I receive cryptic Lua-related errors:
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)  (INITEX)
 system commands enabled.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-en.mkiv (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/syst-ini.mkiv) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/norm-ctx.mkiv) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/syst-pln.mkiv) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/syst-mes.mkiv) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.mkiv<+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua>) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-bas.mkiv loading: ConTeXt Lua Macros / Basic Lua Libraries<+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-bit32.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-lua.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-macro.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-sandbox.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-package.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-lpeg.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-function.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-string.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-table.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-boolean.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-number.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-math.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-io.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-os.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-file.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-gzip.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-md5.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-sha.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-dir.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-unicode.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-url.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-set.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-macro-imp-optimize.lua>) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-lib.mkiv loading: ConTeXt Lua Macros / Libraries<+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-str.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-tab.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-fil.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-sac.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-sto.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-pck.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-prs.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-fmt.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-dim.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/trac-set.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-log.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/trac-inf.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-lua.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-deb.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-tpl.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-seq.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-sta.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-sbx.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-soc-imp-reset.lua><+ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-soc-imp-socket.lua>...e/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-sandbox.lua:180: module 'socket.core' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket.core']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/core/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core/init.lua'
    no file './socket/core.lua'
    no file './socket/core/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './socket/core.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './socket.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in upvalue 'requiem'
    ...e/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-sandbox.lua:180: in function 'require'
    ...texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/util-soc-imp-socket.lua:8: in local 'data'
    ...re/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua:192: in field 'luafilechunk'
    ...re/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua:73: in function 'lua.registercode'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\registerctxluafile #1#2->\ctxlua {lua.registercode("#1","#2")}
                                                               
l.40 \registerctxluafile{util-soc-imp-socket} {}

I verified that lua-socket-3.1.0-3.fc39.aarch64 is installed. I have no idea how to proceed.

Some thoughts:
lua-socket doesn't seem to be detected. I have lua-socket for 5.1 and 5.4 installed:
ls /usr/lib*/lua/*/socket/core.so
/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/socket/core.so
/usr/lib64/lua/5.4/socket/core.so

But LuaTeX seems to be looking for the shared object file for Lua 5.3:
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so'

It's also strange that it keeps trying to look for shared objects in /usr/local/... instead of the standard /usr/ prefix, since my TeX Live was installed via DNF.
I would appreciate any pointers for a fix, or whether I should refer this to the package maintainers, etc.

Maybe this question fits better on the texlive mailing list

The package maintainers missed the patch for ConTeXt when they upgraded their LuaTeX binaries, see https://tug.org/~mseven/luatex.html#socket-context. I sent them that link a year ago, but I guess they forgot about it. The best place to fix this is in the package itself, but you should be able to run the command listed there yourself in the meantime.

On May 30th 2023, Fedora upgraded their LuaTeX binaries to version 1.17.0 to fix a security vulnerability; however, they missed applying a patch needed to make ConTeXt work. I've reported this to the distro maintainers, but for now, you should be able to fix this by running
$ sudo sed -i 's/%primaryflags%/%primaryflags% --socket --shell-escape/' $(type -p mtxrun).lua

luasocket is statically linked into the LuaTeX binaries, but LuaTeX ≥1.17.0 disables it by default. This command modifies the ConTeXt startup script to enable luasocket by default for ConTeXt again. For more details, see my explanation page.

I have fresh Fedora 41 install, with all updates.
And I have similar problem.
I tried to execute:
sudo sed -i 's/%primaryflags%/%primaryflags% --socket --shell-escape/' $(type -p mtxrun).lua

but it gives error:
sed: not possible to read /usr/bin/mtxrun.lua: No such file or catalog

Any ideas how to get ConTeXt running?
Version installed (via yum):
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.04
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2023.03.10 12:15
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkxl/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2023.03.10 12:15

LuaTeX version: 1.17
$ luatex --version This is LuaTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)
Development id: 7581


Please do not post follow-up questions in the answers section. Rather, ask a new question or add a comment. This is not an answer to the original question, I assume?
